# How to benchmark methods from different classes that require arguments?

Tags: c#, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I want to use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to run benchmarks on all three `Run()` methods of the following classes. But it's not clear what the syntax should be.

```cs
class Class1
{
    [Benchmark]
    public bool Run(ref string[] columns)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Class2
{
    [Benchmark]
    public bool Run(ref string[] columns)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Class3
{
    [Benchmark]
    public bool Run(ref string[] columns)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I tried syntax like this.

```cs
BenchmarkRunner.Run<Class1>();
```

But this gives me an error.

> Benchmark method ReadRow has incorrect signature.
> Method shouldn't have any arguments.

Questions:
To compare the performance of these three methods:

- How do I satisfy the argument requirements and eliminate this error?
- How do I compare the performance of the methods? Do I simply call `BenchmarkRunner.Run<Class1>()` for each class, sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I satisfy the argument requirements and eliminate this error?

Create class containing parameterless benchmark method and invoke the becnhmarked method there passing parameters. Either create the param in-place or use some precreated ones:

```cs
class MyBenchmark
{
    [Benchmark]
    public bool RunClass1()
    {    
        var columns = // create string[]; maybe use field to store it
        new Class1().BenchmarkedMethod(ref columns);
    }
}
```

Also check the docs articles on:

- [Parameterization](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/features/parameterization.html)
- [Setup (and clean up if needed)](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/features/setup-and-cleanup.html)

If needed approaches specified there will allow to move instance and parameter creation out of the benchmarked methods.

> How do I compare the performance of the methods

Move all method inside one benchmark class.

```
class MyBenchmark
{
    [Benchmark]
    public bool RunClass1()
    {    
        var columns = // create string[];
        return new Class1().BenchmarkedMethod(ref columns);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool RunClass2()
    {    
        var columns = // create string[];
        return new Class2().BenchmarkedMethod(ref columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm allocating class instances and that time is being included in the benchmark.

Comment: @JonathanWood without seeing the actual code it is hard to tell the best approach, but as written in the comment in the first snippet - you can move the instance creation to field. Also check the links for samples.